# Copy SPList from one site to another

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, migration

For a SP2010 migration tool I have written two methods: one for exporting the site collection to a xml-file and one for importing a xml-structure to a site collection.

Everything works fine except for the fact that I can't get the list migration to work properly. I just need to copy the list without it's contents but with attributes like what template is being used and if it is displayed in the quicklaunch bar.

Here I store the data about each list in an xml file

```
foreach (SPList list in rootsite.Lists)
{
     //Store relevant data about each list in xml node
     XmlElement nodelist = document.CreateElement(strList);
     nodelist.SetAttribute(strTitle, list.Title);
     nodelist.SetAttribute(strDescription, list.Description);
     nodelist.SetAttribute(strTemplate, "value for list template goes here");
}
```

And here I convert the xml to SPList:

```
XmlElement rootnode = document.DocumentElement; //Get root node of document (SPSite)
XmlNodeList listsnode = rootnode.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes(strList); //Get all lists from "Lists" node of xml file

if (listsnode.Count > 0) 
{
     foreach(XmlNode node in listsnode)
     {
           //Store data about list in strings and create the list afterward
           string strListTitle = node.Attributes[strTitle].Value;
           string strListDescription = node.Attributes[strDescription].Value;
           string strListTemplate = //how to get data into SPListTemplate here?

           site.RootWeb.Lists.Add(strListTitle, strListDescription, strListTemplate);
     }
}
```

So I basically do not know how to approach this and if I should use SPListTemplate or SPListTemplateType.

Comment: You can use "Save list as template" functionality to move list.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/save-list-as-a-template-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/
Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I need all the data in my xml file so correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't this just save the template as a file?

Comment: Yes, but you can easily move this file with custom utility and then restore it on destination server. I am saying it because it could very hard to correctly save and transfer all list's metadata. This can include content types, fields, version settings, etc.

Comment: Actually if you really want you can unpackage stp template, get its xml file and save it in your xml file. Then during restore you'll have to package this xml file again and push it to sharepoint.

Comment: interesting approach, will give this a try tomorrow. will this also copy custom fields/content types I have set up for my templates?